# Error occurred when upgrading to 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish from 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I recently upgraded to Jammy Jellyfish on my Acer 7720 laptop from 20.04 but mid way through the installation process, an error occurred. the error displayed a white screen saying "oh no, something went wrong, contact system administrator".

Now, I tried to find a way to get out of that screen and found that I could type `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F3` which took me to a `tty3` screen where i could input my login details, however I had forgotten both my login and password.

I tried to see if I could change my Ubuntu One password as I thought perhaps both could be connected in terms of login details and then come back to the tty3 screen, but when I tried to put in the login details in the tty3 screen, it didn't seem to go through.

I then thought the password can't be the issue, i think, but the login/username.

For the login/username issue I tried researching how I could find it to which I then found a method where I could access the GRUB system by constantly pressing the shift key and then go to another screen to which i then typed a code: `awk -F: '$3 == 1000' /etc/passwd` , where I could potentially find my username in the first line of the code. When I worked out where I could find my username, albeit still in doubt of if it could be by username,  I went back to the tty3 screen and inputted all the possibilities and it still didn't work.

Now I am still stuck with the same error message and cannot access my laptop through any means.

Could someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all these cascading problems by reinstalling Ubuntu:

- Use a different system to make an Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB installer.
- Boot from it.
- Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to backup your data, since you seem prone to problems.
- Then use the "Install Ubuntu" option to reinstall Ubuntu. Set a password that you will remember.